# Specify which panned tab to be opened in ADF

Tags: jsf, tabs, oracle-adf

Is there a way to specify which tabbed panel to be opened in an ADF project. For example, we have a view page with tabbed panel. We have a button which leads to a new task flow and when we return from it we should be on a particular panel box in the tabbed panel.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , always mention your Jdev version.

You can create a binding for panel Tabbed component like

```
 RichPanelTabbed rpt = getMyPanelTabbedBinding();
```

Next , you would have to find which ShowDetailItem to show and then you can call setDisclosed() on RichShowDetailItem's object like below :

```
List<UiComponent> myChildList = richPanelTabbed.getChildren();
RichShowDetailItem sdi = myChildList.get(0);
sdi.setDisclosed(true);
```

From this you can set disclosed tab as per your wish.
For more, search with "open panel tab programatically in ADF".

-Sid

Comment: I added AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget at the end but I noticed that the tabs are right opened when I refresh the page. How can it be done automatically?